# Conditional (ternary) operator in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to add conditional (ternary) operator in the blade to Laravel like:

```
<select name="staff" id="staff" class="form-control placeholder>
  <option value="0">{{ __('messages.Select Staff') }}</option>
  @if($staff != "Empty Staff")
   @foreach ($staff as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->id}}" {{$item->stafftime->states == 'open' ? 'disabled' : ''}}>{{$item->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
   @else
   <option value='0'> __('messages.Empty Staff')</option>
@endif
</select>
```

in my model staff and stafftime like blow:

```
    protected $table = "stafftimes";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'starttime', 'endtime', 'states', 'staff_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];  // Hide The Variable from select

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Staff', 'staff_id', 'id');
    }
```

and in my staff model like:

```
    protected $table = "staffs";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'mobile'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];  // Hide The Variable from select


    public $timestamps = false;

    public function stafftime()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Stafftime', 'staff_id', 'id');
    }
```

I have an error

> Property [states] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: the `stafftime` relationship is a "Has Many" so it returns a Collection not a single model instance .... it is returning a Collection potentially containing many `StaffTime` models ... you would have to get a single model from that collection to access that model's attributes

Comment: so what is the solution !!

Comment: "you would have to get a single model from that Collection to access that model's attributes" ... which of the potentially many models in that Collection do you want to access the `states` attribute for?

Comment: yes i want to access the states attribute

Comment: the Collection can potentially have many `StaffTime` model instances in it ... which one of those many do you want to access? if there was 10 in the Collection which particular ONE do you want to access?

Comment: i want to access the open states in each option

Comment: again, the collection can have many many records, which one of those many records do you want to do this check of the 'states' attribute for to see if it is set to 'open'?

Comment: staff who has states open in stafftime model

Comment: so if there are 10 StaffTime models in the Collection, if any of them have 'states' set to 'open' is what you want? if all of them? ...

Comment: You don't seem to understand what @lagbox is saying. I'll give it a shot; When you do `$item->stafftime`, you will get a **collection** (a list) of **all** records with that staff_id, no matter what the `states` are. When you do: `$item->staffTime->states`, you're checking it _on a collection of entities_ that can have _different_ states so comparing the _collection_ against _one single string_ makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: yes  any of them have 'states' set to 'open'

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a Collection that could potentially contain many Model instances when you access the dynamic property `stafftime` on a `Staff` model. If you want to know if **any** of those `StaffTime` instances has the attribute 'states' set to 'open' you could use the `contains` method of the Collection class:

```
$item->stafftime->toBase()->contains('states', 'open')
```

This would give you a boolean to use for your ternary condition.

The reason `toBase()` is called there is because an Eloquent Collection (which the realtionship uses) overrides the `contains` method to have different functionality, so we want to convert the Eloquent Collection to a regular Collection to be able to use the normal `contains` functionality.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains) - `contains`

Comment: $item->staffTime->toBase()->contains('states', 'open') works done thank you

Comment: no problem, please feel free to mark as accepted if it worked for you .. good luck and have fun with Laravel